# How can you remove icons from the Eclipse/MyEclipse main toolbar?

Tags: icons, eclipse, toolbar

I could get enough screen space for a few more lines of code by removing some icons from my MyEclipse toolbar.  There are some icons I'd like to keep, so hiding the toolbar altogether isn't what I'm looking for.  I've found plenty of instructions in the help files and online for moving icons around, but none for removing them.  Is it possible to customize the toolbar to include only the icons you want?  If so, how?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648215/how-to-customize-a-toolbar-in-eclipse

Comment: Official Doc: https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9n.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, I found it.  It's hidden under the perspectives settings, since the toolbar changes based on the active perspective.

There's no direct label for toolbar icons, but they're toggleable under `Window > Customize Perspective`, at least in MyEclipse 7.5.  You have to manually flip through the Command Groups list and look at the Toolbar Details pane on the right side.  When you see an icon you don't want, uncheck the associated command group.  This also influences the contents of Eclipse's menu bars, though.